# Read input and echo this else that with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm working on a form.php file which is structured below:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <input name="answer" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

...and I want to add some php or javascript code which will read the value of the input field that the user will type and if the value is equal to a then echo true else echo false. Until now, I made some attempts like the one below but don't work.

```
<?php
    $_POST($answer);

    if ($answer == "a") {
        echo "True";
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }
?>
```

Maybe is not that simple as I think. Any ideas or better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was quite correct I've just added a few improvements

```
 <?php
    $answer = isset($_POST['answer']) ? $_POST['answer'] : null;
    if ($answer == "a") {
        echo "True";
    } else if (!is_null($answer)) {
        echo "False";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki there was a code in my answer as well, but it wasn't displayed by some reason. I've just edited it

Comment: Correct, thanks! But false statement is shown before the user make an answer.

Comment: @Oleksandr You did fantastic job, everything is working nice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must retrieve the named value 'answer' on the `$_POST` **array** into your var `$answer`:

```
<?php
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];

    if ($answer == "a") {
        echo "True";
    } else {
        echo "False";
    }
?>
```

[See docs for further reference!](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Your answer is also correct (thanks) but I have the same problem as Olksandr code. A true/false statement is shown after the complete load of the webpage before the user make an answer.